# Rspec new expectation syntax

Tags: rspec2, rspec-rails

I've the following rspec unit test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Article do
  describe ".recents" do
    it "includes articles created less than one week ago" do
      article = Article.create(created_at: Date.today - 1.week + 1.second)
      expect(Article.recents).to eql([article])
    end

    it "excludes articles published at midnight one week ago" do
      article = Article.create!(:created_at => Date.today - 1.week)
      expect(Article.recents).to be_empty
    end

  end
end
```

and the `Article`model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name, :price, :created_at

  scope :recents, where('created_at <= ?', 1.week.ago)
end
```

when I run my tests I get:

```
1) Article.recents includes articles created less than one week ago
     Failure/Error: expect(Article.recents).to eql([article])

       expected: [#<Article id: 60, name: nil, description: nil, price: nil, created_at: "2012-11-14 00:00:01", updated_at: "2012-11-21 10:12:33", section_id: nil>]
            got: [#<Article id: 60, name: nil, description: nil, price: nil, created_at: "2012-11-14 00:00:01", updated_at: "2012-11-21 10:12:33", section_id: nil>]

       (compared using eql?)

       Diff:#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ff692bce158>.==([#<Article id: 60, name: nil, description: nil, price: nil, created_at: "2012-11-14 00:00:01", updated_at: "2012-11-21 10:12:33", section_id: nil>]) returned false even though the diff between #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ff692bce158> and [#<Article id: 60, name: nil, description: nil, price: nil, created_at: "2012-11-14 00:00:01", updated_at: "2012-11-21 10:12:33", section_id: nil>] is empty. Check the implementation of #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ff692bce158>.==.
     # ./spec/models/article_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Could someone please help me to figure out what's the error in my test?

It seems good for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing an activerecord relation (`Article.recents`) to an array (`[article]`), which is why the expectation is failing. (It looks like they are the same in the spec results because `inspect` converts the relation into an array before printing it out.)

Change your first expectation to this:

```
expect(Article.recents.to_a).to eql([article])
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to work but shouldn't it be commented on the docs. about the need to convert to an `Array` before doing a comparison?

Comment: It's not really an rspec issue, so there's no need to document it. In a console try the same thing, i.e. : `Article.recents.eql?([article])` and you'll see the result is `false`, because `Article.recents` is an ActiveRecord::Relation whereas `[article]` is an Array.